# Método POST não pega valor do FORM

Tags: php, html5, formulário, email

Estou fazendo um formulário de contato em um site, mas o método do PHP não pega o valor do `input` no `form`, já pesquisei na internet e não consegui achar ninguém com o mesmo problema.

E e-mail está sendo enviado, o valor do campo `$subject` que eu seto na mão vem no e-mail, o restante não é preenchido.

Segue meu form:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="contato-nome" id="contato-nome" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Nome">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="contato-email" id="contato-email" type="email" class="form-control" required placeholder="E-mail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="contato-mensagem" id="contato-mensagem" required class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Mensagem" ></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Enviar Mensagem</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Segue o `sendmail.php`

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email enviado!'
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["contato-nome"]));
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["contato-email"])); 
$subject = "E-Mail enviado através do site samamba.com.br"; 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST["contato-mensagem"])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'felipesamamba@gmail.com';

$body = 'Nome: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Assunto: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Menssagem: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

Adicionado:
Parece que encontrei o foco do problema, existe um javascript para exibir a mensagem de e-mail enviada com sucesso, e quando eu tiro ele, o e-mail envia normalmente, mas não aparece a mensagem de que o e-mail foi enviado, direciona para uma página que imprime o array.
Gostaria de manter como era, mas que os dados fossem enviados pro POST

```
//Ajax contact
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Da um `print_r($_POST); die('...');` na primeira linha do `sedmail.php` e vê oque aparece.

Comment: Não aparece nada, vem vazio.

Comment: Não aparece nada ou retorna um array vazio?

Comment: Não aparece nada. Coloquei pra imprimir o $_POST no div onde mostra a mensagem de sucesso no HTML, e também não aparece nada.

Comment: Como vc sabe que o email é enviado? pelo `$status`?, confira o nome arquivo e do action, de um print_r em `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Eu recebo o e-mail. Mas com os campos em vazio. 
Adicionei mais informações, que ao que me parece, é o foco do problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se o envio é feito por ajax não esqueça de mandar todos o campos do form 'manualmente', definindo um atributo e serializando o form pelo id

```
 $.post($("#main-contact-form").attr('action'), $("#main-contact-form").serialize)
        .done(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
         });
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Não tenho muito conhecimento em AJAX. Usei esse script que me mandou, e não funcionou. Teria como me dar uma ajuda em criar esse script que envia os campos manualmente?
E obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Descobri o problema a partir da resposta do rray.
Faltava serializar o atributo. Usei o seguinte ajax e funcionou corretamente!

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {'use strict',
    $this = $(this);    
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $this.serialize(), function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```